# Перевести 'life story' в контексте

Tags: перевод

Подскажите, будет ли стилистически верным дословный перевод 'life story' в данном контексте:

> They had their life story turned into a movie.

перевод:

> По их истории жизни был снят фильм.

Comment: Лучше "по истории ИХ жизни". А какие вы еще варианты видите? "Жизнеописание"?

Comment: @Artemix, так действительно вопрос решается, местоимение не на месте, поэтому и читалось не по-русски

Comment: *История* is not the best way to translate "story" here. Just use *об их жизни сняли фильм*.

Comment: Может, "По их биографии сняли фильм."?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, биография воспринимается как что-то написанное на носителе, а тут просто факты, события из жизни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее подходящим вариантом для меня оказался:

> (В 2003 году) был снят фильм, основанный на их жизни.

Comment: Там дословно будет: *История их жизни превращена в фильм.*